# Add a button section Header?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView with two section I want to add a button in section header(Action Button) It is possible to do same in the sample image?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if(section ==0)
{
    return 0;
}
else{
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 20.0)];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(275.0, 5.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    button.tag = section;
    button.hidden = NO;
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(insertParameter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [myView addSubview:button];
    return myView;    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Bhargavi UIView* View = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0)];

 // create the button object
 UIButton * headerBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 headerBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 headerBtn.opaque = NO;
 headerBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0);
 [headerBtn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[headerBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(ActionEventForButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [View addSubview:headerBtn];

 return View;

Comment: If you tried that in viewForHeaderInSection then what is the problem?

Comment: @Bhargavi pls check my code

Comment: is it not showing the button?

Comment: have you debug whether it is going at else condition or not

Comment: Hey check this CGRectMake(0.0, 5.0, 30.0, 30.0) just for testing

Comment: checked already same problem

Comment: i edited my answer . i think it is the problem of view height. it is too small

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this May be it helps you,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //Headerview
    UIView *myView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 20.0)] autorelease];
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(275.0, 5.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    button.tag = section;
    button.hidden = NO;
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(insertParameter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [myView addSubview:button];
      return myView;
}
```

you can change the height of the header section here

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 40.0;
}
```

for getting same Button image you can take your custom image ,by using default image you can't show like that.

Comment: in first section button was not coming because you didn't kept remaining sections button was coming what's you'r problem?what you want exactly?

Comment: I want button in section header same in the sample image

Comment: once see that image, you want like this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26225/discussion-between-sunny-and-ios234)

Comment: pls come to chat one more doubt pls..simple doubt only

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible.
for that you have to create your custom `View` with `UIButton` and return from the UITableView Delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 ///your implementation
  return customView;
}
```

make your view height 45 instead of 20. its too small.

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 20.0)];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is the `button` frame is `(275.0, 5.0, 30.0, 30.0`), but the `myView` frame is `(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 20.0)`. 
The height of the `button` is 30, but `myView` is 20 only.
The Y position of the `button` is 5, so the `myView` height needs to be 40.

change the `myView` frame as (0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 40.0).

And the height of the section also set to 40 using `heightForHeaderInSection`: delegate method.

Simply follow this steps....

1. set `myView` frame as `(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 40.0)`.
2. set `button` frame as `(275.0, 5.0, 300.0, 20.0)`.
3. set the height of the section as 40 using `heightForHeaderInSection` delegate method.

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

set the height of the header view

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 81;

}
```